# Logitech Touchpad T650 does not click

Tags: touchpad, logitech

I have just received this Logitech Touchpad T650. The problem is that on my Ubuntu 12.10 desktop, the left or right tap clicks don't work while I can navigate and scroll with the touchpad. Any ideas to fix this?
Thanks

Comment: Related question: http://askubuntu.com/q/229883/6969

Answer (score 1):

As far as I've read/found, it behaves like a basic laptop touchpad on Ubuntu with the exception of two-finger scrolling (old school, not natural like touch screens). Tap clicks don't work and there aren't any pointer tools for it like those available for Windows...

For those wondering, it sort of gets the job done, but it's not really fully working yet. Unless some update has escaped me, the T650 is definitely NOT worth buying for Ubuntu machines right now.

Answer (score 0):

You need to update the touchpad T650 firmware. In order to do that, you will need a Windows box.

Go to the link below and follow instructions.

http://www.logitech.com/en-us/support/touchpad-t650?section=downloads&crid=398&bit=32&osid=14&softwareid=11370

After firmware upgrade, it's working as expected on Ubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

I am adding this to expand on the [firmware upgrade](http://support.logitech.com/en_us/product/10337), which helps to enable all functionality under linux.

I have spent some time figuring out how the update works, so I want to leave it for you to pick up when needed.

You will NOT do this with the USB cable connected, this update happens via BT:

1. You need to download the '**Logitech Unifying Software**' (LUS) from the same page above and install it on a windows box (There is no firmware update you can download for XP, I did this on W7 via VirtualBox VM)
2. You need to download the update file that is called something like: **RQM_041_001_00038.exe**, and RUN it, seemingly nothing happens, but the file copies itself from to the LUS install location so it can be picked up
3. Restart
4. Start LUS and click 'Advanced' to see the paired devices
5. Add the touchpad by switching it ON with the receiver in USB

I use the same brand keyboard, so it is useful to look at something like **Solaar** package to enable use of just **one receiver** for **both devices**.

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:daniel.pavel/solaar
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install solaar
```

Answer (score 0):

On most Ubuntu distros 18.04 and beyond, at least, the Logitech T650 works fine; I use it everyday. There is one caveat with Lubuntu/Kubuntu, i.e., the KDE desktop; tapping-as-click and "natural scrolling" are not enabled by default. To enable them, you must run `xinput` and the appropriate commands. An example sequence is below. It's possible that installing `synclient` might fix these issues more permanently, but I found the default config with `synclient` even worse, so I abandoned it.

Here's an example sequence:

`xinput`

Check your devices; look for the Logitech touchpad's device number. Let's pretend it's number 12.

`xinput list-props 12`

Look for the `libinput tapping enabled` and `libinput natural scrolling enabled` to find their numbers. Let's pretend tapping is 290. 0 is off, 1 is on.

`xinput set-prop 12 290 1`

Unfortunately, this resets every time the computer restarts; I've yet to figure out how to make the changes permanent, though it may just be that I need to sign in as root or something. You can write a bash script to speed it up, but the number assigned to the device will sometimes change, meaning you may need to include a variety of numbers to ensure you'll get the slot it's using at the moment.